# Detect Videocard Type Without Drivers Installed

Tags: driver

Good morning fellow technology Specialists!

I am attempting to determine some identifying information for a video card that is physically installed yet without drivers. It is my attempt to detect some sort of Identifying information about the videocard prior to driver install. Is there a way to do this?

Reason for this question is I wish to develop a script that will run on a freshly installed image, detect a given video card (if possible), and install the appropriate drivers based on some given identifier.

Let me know what you guys suggest. Looking through regedit and googling has yielded me nothing at this point, I turn to some who may know better.

Comment: Say more about the environment. Is it a PC or your custom hardware? If PC what OS?

Comment: It will be 3 Different PC model types. But I am on the right track now. Martin was thinking about it right when he brought up the linux command lspci. I should have thought about it that way! I am now going through WMI and will parse the info out that i need. Ill post the Powershell script once i finish for others that have this issue! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that all your graphics cards are PCI(e) cards. If so you could go by the vendor and product IDs of the cards installed in your system. These IDs are also used by the operating system to identify the right driver for each device. Linux comes with a tool to show them. On my computer I get:

```
$ lspci -nn | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 620 [8086:5917] (rev 07)
```

The relevant IDs are in square brackets, the first one is the vendor ID, the second part is the device ID. [For Windows there seem to be similar tools](https://arstechnica.com/civis/viewtopic.php?t=1110172). You can find databases on the web that map these IDs to vendor and product names, for example [here](https://pcisig.com/membership/member-companies) or [here](https://pcilookup.com/) in case you want to find out IDs for cards you don't have at hand.

Comment: I am reading this now. Ill will update my post if it proves helpful! this is definitely a good start. Ill see what I can do.

Comment: I am writing out the Powershell Script for it now. Nice approach Martin. I should have thought about it through how Linux would do it. Ill be using WMI to pull the info. Ill post it when im done for others to reference.